# Get transactions amount repeated day by day

Tags: postgresql, algorithm

I have `transactions` table with columns `id, user_id, currency, amount, created_at`;

I want to write function to check in last x days transaction with exist amount repeated or not.

For example user makes transaction per 200$ in 5 days, and **6th** days wants to make transaction in **250$**. In that time i have to check did user make transaction in last 5 days per 250$ or not. In this example function have to return `false`. Because user breaks rule.

If user want to make transaction with 200$ function have to return `true`;

How can I solve this problem. I have no any idea.

Comment: What have **YOU** tried so far? Where exactly did you get stuck? Post your code.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I have no idea how can I calculate this. Can I get day by day with loop, bu I think It is incorrect way. That's way I have created question

Comment: I have to calculate 2 transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select count(*) from  "Transactions" where "created_at">= NOW()- INTERVAL '5 DAY' and "amount"=250 and "currency" = "USD"